# Haskell: check if two lists are equal

Tags: list, haskell

I want to check if two lists `A` and `B` are equal, i.e., `a1 == b1, a2 == b2`,...

I have a working solution:

```
all (\x->x) zipWith $ (==) A B
```

Another idea is to do it recursively: `a:as, b:bs` ; check if `a1==b1` and call the function with the remaining lists `as` and `bs`. But isn't there an easier and more readable way to do this?

Comment: If your lists have always same size then just `A == B`.

Comment: Also if your lists don't have the same size, just `as == bs` tells you if they are equal.

Comment: @Ingo @mort's "working" solution treats, for example, `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]` as equal, there `(==)` would not.

Comment: I didn't mention list length because it's easy to check. But if == is false if the two lists don't have the same length, it's even better.

Comment: Matvey - I actually assumed that his working solution is not really working as he wants. Should have made that explicit.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can just use `==` on them directly.

```
> [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
True
> [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2]
False
```

This is because `==` is part of the `Eq` type class, and there is an `Eq` instance for lists which looks something like this:

```
instance Eq a => Eq [a]
```

This means that lists instantiate `Eq` as long as the element type also instantiates `Eq`, which is the case for all types defined in the standard Prelude except functions and `IO` actions.

Answer (score 49):

First, hammar's answer is correct, so accept his answer please. (Edit: Which you have done, thank you.)

```
listA == listB
```

(I'm going to nitpick on small details in your question, mostly for the benefit of future beginners who find this page on Google.)

Second, `A` and `B` aren't lists: they start with upper case letters, so they cannot be variables. I'm going to call them `listA` and `listB` instead.

Third, there is a typo in your working solution: the `$` should be before the `zipWith`, not after. The way it appears in your question results in a compile error. I think you meant this:

```
all (\x->x) $ zipWith (==) listA listB
```

Fourth, `(\x->x)` is better known as the function `id`.

```
all id $ zipWith (==) listA listB
```

Fifth, as Matvey points out, `all id` is the same as `and`.

```
and $ zipWith (==) listA listB
```

Sixth, these do different things when the lists have different lengths. Using `(==)` directly on lists will result in `False`, whereas `zipWith` will ignore the excess elements. That is:

```
[1,2,3] == [1,2]                   -- False
and $ zipWith (==) [1,2,3] [1,2]   -- True
```

Now, there are probably situations when you want the second behaviour. But you almost certainly want the first behaviour.

Finally, to emphasise, just use `(==)` directly on the lists:

```
listA == listB
```

Comment: I read your first sentence as "First, hammar's answer is incorrect, so accept this answer please."

Comment: Yes, very blurry letters. Turn off your keyboard's anti-aliasing :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can replace `all (\x -> x)` with `and`.