# Storing values outside of promises in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, promise, protractor

I have a timeline kind of feature in my angular app which has name of player and his description under. The name of all players share a common class called `player-title.ng-binding` and the description of all players share a common class called `.player-description.ng-binding`

In order to get all the names and respective descriptions I have done the following.

```
  element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding')).getText().then(function(name){
        //prints name of first player
        console.log(name[0]);
  });


  element.all(by.css('.player-description.ng-binding')).getText().then(function(description){
        //prints description of first player
        console.log(description[0]);
  });
```

However I am not able to think of a way to check that each player has the right description. For instance something like `expect(name[0]).toEqual(description[0]);` I am new to promises and all and would love any inputs in this matter.

Lastly I also noticed when I did something like this it printed undefined.

```
  var name = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding')).getText().then(function(name){

  });

  console.log(name[0]);
```

Html Code for the players

```
 <!-- player -->
  <h4 class="font-thin m-t-lg m-b-lg text-primary-lt">Sponsor player</h4>
  <p></p>
  <div class="player m-l-sm m-r-sm b-info b-l">
    <div  ng-repeat = "player in formattedplayerData | orderBy : '-Name'">
      <div class = "tl-item">
        <i class="pull-left player-badge {{player.class}} "></i>
        <div class="m-l-lg">
          <div class="player-title">{{player.Name}}</div>
          <p class="player-description">{{player.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / player -->
```

I would appreciate all inputs on this matter.

Comment: Please show an example HTML for a single player.

Comment: do you mean like a screenshot?@alecxe

Comment: Nope, the HTML source code of the player section. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe, I have added the html source code. Please let me know if you require anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check that `name` is equal to `description`:

```
var name = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'))
  .first()
  .getText();

var description = element.all(by.css('.player-description.ng-binding'))
  .first()
  .getText();

var nameEqualsDesc = Promise.all([name, description]).then(function(info) {
  var name = info[0], description = info[1];
  return name === description;
});

expect(nameEqualsDesc).toBe(true);
```

To check that each name and description is correct:

```
var correctNames = [...];
var correctDescriptions = [...];
var names = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'));
var descriptions = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'));
for (var i = 0; i < correctNames.length; i++) {
  expect(names.get(i).getText()).toEqual(correctNames[i]);
  expect(descriptions.get(i).getText()).toEqual(correctDescriptions[i]);
}
```

For more info, check out [ElementArrayFinder#get](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get)

EDIT: To check that all names are equal to all descriptions (as requested in comment):

```
var names = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'))
  .map(getText);
var descriptions = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'))
  .map(getText);

var namesEqualDescriptions = Promise.all([names, descriptions])
  .then(function(results) {
    return results[0].every(function(name, index) {
      return name === results[1][index];
    });
  });

expect(namesEqualDescriptions).toBe(true);
```

This solution uses [map](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) as specified in the answer by @alecxe, along with [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

**Additional Info:**

Remember that promises are *asynchronous*, so in your last code block, when you `console.log(name[0])`, `name` is an instance of a promise, which has no property `0`, and that's why you get undefined.

`expect` in protractor [understands promises](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/128), so you can give a promise to `expect()` and it will know to unwrap it and check its actual value.

Also remember that promises *unwrap*, which means if you return a promise within a `then()` call the variable you assigned the original promise to will be fulfilled with that value, e.g.

```
var p = Promise.resolve(2).then((x) => Promise.resolve(x * x));
p.then(console.log.bind(console)); // will log 4 (2 * 2)
```

So to get what you want, you could return the name and the description from two different promises, and then give those promises to `expect`.

Also, you can use [first](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) instead of having to use `then` with an index.

```
var name = element.all(by.css('.player-title.ng-binding'))
  .first()
  .getText();

var description = element.all(by.css('.player-description.ng-binding'))
  .first()
  .getText();

expect(name).toEqual('name');
expect(description).toEqual('description');
```

**Key Takeaways**

- Promises can be confusing, but [using them correctly](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/) will make your life with them a lot easier.
- `ElementArrayFinder` methods can be used to access different elements within element collections
- `Promise.all` can be used to "join" on completions of promises
- List operation methods like `every`, `some`, and `reduce` can be used to produce information about how two collections relate to each other. IMHO it really [should be easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339264/haskell-check-if-two-lists-are-equal) ;)

Comment: I am just going through your suggestion as we speak, Technically both name and description are like arrays of same length and i would want to check for all. And when i check I mean if name[0] = Jordan, description[0] should say "Best ever", which can only be found in description[0] and not description[1] etc.

Comment: Added solution under the main code block. Let me know if you have any other questions or it's still unclear :)

Comment: I don't your "unwrap example". There doesn't seem to be a promise returned from the callback?

Comment: Updated. The idea is to still use Promise.all and then simply compare the lists.

Answer (score 1):

A more "protractoric" approach would be to use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map):

```
var players = element.all(by.css("div.tl-item")).map(function (player) {
    return {
        name: player.element(by.css("div.player-title")).getText(),
        description: player.element(by.css("p.player-description")).getText()
    }
});
```

Here the `players` variable would contain a promise that would result into an *array of player objects*. If you want to see the actual value of the `players`, resolve the promise:

```
players.then(function (playersValue) {
    console.log(playersValue);
});
```

Or, you can expect it to be equal to an expected array:

```
expect(players).toEqual([
    {name: "Player 1", description: "Player description 1"},
    {name: "Player 2", description: "Player description 2"}
]);
```

Or, you can get players by index:

```
players.then(function (playersValue) {
    expect(playersValue[0].name).toEqual("Player 1");
    expect(playersValue[0].description).toEqual("Player description 1");
});
```

Comment: would you then be able to use `toEqual` without having to manually use `then`?

Comment: @TravisKaufman yes, from what I recall, we can write smth like e.g. `expect(players[0].name).toEqual("Player 1");`. Thanks.

Comment: hmm according to [the source code](https://github.com/angular/jasminewd/blob/master/index.js#L215-L225), it looks like it checks whether or not what's passed to it is a promise. Since `players` is a promise, `players[0]` would return undefined so wouldn't those lines throw a `ReferenceError`?

Comment: @TravisKaufman yeah, tried to find an example of getting the first item of a promise which would be resolved into an array, but could not. I'm afraid you are right, we have to use `then()`. But, let's wait for the OP to try it out and come back. Thank you!

Comment: I just got chance to finish to try solution posted by @TravisKaufman now i will try yours. sorry for delay.

Comment: @alecxe i tried out your solution but it seems when i try expect(players[0].name).toEqual("Player 1"); I get and undefined error. Without the except it is working fine.

Comment: @user1010101 yup, this is what Travis was talking about. I've updated the answer and included a way to get the players by index. Thanks for trying it out!

Comment: @user1010101 IMHO, Travis deserves to have an accepted answer here. The effort he produced is much more than mine. Plus, he helped me to understand that `players[0]` would not be resolved by `expect()`. But, I still like the `map()` option :)

Comment: @user1010101 thanks, you can use a similar loop as Travis provided in his answer. But, why do you need to loop over the players? You can expect the complete array as provided in the answer..

Comment: @user1010101 got it, I think I fixed it, check it out (using `by.repeater()` now).